# Help with rplidar and autuonmus navigation

Tags: ros, rplidar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone
I'm a beginner on ROS, I'm trying to make an autuonmus robot using an rplidar and encoder.
Here is what I have done so far

1. I installed ROS kinetic on a Raspberry pi 3
2. I got the rplidar running and I can get the data on rviz map
3. I have my encoders and motors controlled by a UNO Arduino

Now, I'm stuck on the next step
I don't how to use the rplidar data, I'm not sure if I need to install any more packages ( like SLAM )
and I also, I have no clue how to connect my raspberry pi ( ROS ) to the arduino and transfer the rplidar data to the motor

PLEASE help with a clear ( step by step ) on what to do so I can make my research based on that.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296820/help-with-rplidar-and-autuonmus-navigation/) by [hamzh.albar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36205/hamzh.albar@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-09**:
There are many questions here. I suggest that to get better help, you break your question into many, directed questions that are ROS-related.

**Comment by [hamzh.albar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36205/hamzh.albar@gmail.com/) on 2018-07-10**:
Thank you for the editing, I actually don't want detailed answers. Just a step by step on what need to be done.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

You will first need to get familiar with the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). I found it helpful to go over some tutorials with an existing robot such as the turtlebot or [clearpath husky](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/HuskyMove.html) for autonomous navigation. By going over these tutorials, you should become familiar with things like move_base (local and global path planners and their parameters). After this, you may use a package such as [this](https://github.com/NickL77/RPLidar_Hector_SLAM) which allows you to use your rplidar to conduct hector slam. Keep in mind that this package is only for mapping, you will still need to launch move_base in order to achieve navigation.

Hope that helps,

Aaron

---

Originally posted by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) with karma: 135 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0